# Uncaught ReferenceError: _typeface_js is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have loaded typeface.js and it's working well in firefox, but in chrome it gives me the following errors:

Header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.extensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="typeface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: _typeface_js is not defined

```
$(document).ready(function(){

_typeface_js.initialize()

QueryLoader.selectorPreload = "body";
QueryLoader.init();

$('.vertical-center').show();

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.header').css({
        width:Math.min(($(window).width()-($(window).width() - 1219)/2), 1219)+'px'
    });

    $('.vertical-center').css({
        left: ($(window).width() - 1219)/2+'px',
        top: ($(window).height() - 621)/2+'px'
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your browser developer tools. The "typeface" file is probably not being loaded properly.

Comment: what version of typeface.js you are using?